# Android App Update creation

Tags: android

I have created an android app.But it is not available on playstore because of some security issues.I have'nt released the first version I have some more features to add later.So my question is how can i give update to my customers.For automatic update what should I do in the current app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update (increment) the version code in the AndroidManifest.xml file, then Google Play will detect it's an update. When you upload it Google Play does pretty much everything for you.

Comment: but I dont want to put my app in playstore. then what I have to do.?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood. All I can think of is (if you know your customers) ask them to delete existing version, and send them the new APK (ensuring they have set up third party installs as yes). Hope this helps.

Comment: Like those third party websites that keep trying to get me to load up my APK's instead of putting them on Google Play? (e.g. http://apps.opera.com/) Never used them myself, sorry.